# Given a bitstring generate all bitstring with n flipped bits

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, bit-manipulation

For an algorithm I need to be able to iterate over all bit strings where $k$ bits are flipped given a bit string with length $n$ and $n \geq k$. For instance let's say I have the bit string $1001$ and I want to have all bit strings with $2$ bits flipped. That should result in the following bit strings:

```
1010
1100
1110
0000
0011
0101
```

So given a bit string of length $n$ and where $k$ bits will be flipped the result will be $\binom{n}{k}$ bit strings. Is there an efficient way to generate all of them? The bit strings I have as input are just unsigned integers so I can use bit twiddling!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let your initial bit string be `x`.

For all numbers `b` with `k` bits set (i.e. where `k` bits are 1), output `x xor b`.

Finding all numbers with `k` bits set is described elsewhere, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2075867/838494)